# providing access to post_id or post inside functions.php

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, hooks, page-template

I'm trying to add metaboxes to the bottom of any post which is created from a specific post template. 
ie I don't want metaboxes on all my posts, just certain posts.

At the point when I decided to add the actions to draw and save metabox data, if I had access to the post I could look to see what template it uses and either continue to draw the metaboxes or quit.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'post_metabox_setup');

function post_metabox_setup() {
  //decide whether to add draw and save actions here
}
```

How do I access either $post or $post_id in my 'post_metabox_setup function'.
I've tried just doing this :

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'post_metabox_setup');

function post_metabox_setup($post_id) {
  //but here $post_id an empty string when the post loads in the editor
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the standard [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) hook which gives you the proper post object via the second argument?

Comment: @SallyCJ I didn't know it existed! I'm new to wordpress. All the examples of adding metaboxes use load-post. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. :) But that's the hook you should be using for registering custom meta boxes. Or you can also use [`add_meta_boxes_{$post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes_post_type/) where the first (and the only) argument is the post object.

Comment: @SallyCJ While I have you, do you know how to add an image picker metabox.. So when creating blocks you can add wp.editor.MediaUpload to the 'InspectorControls'.
Can I somehow use MediaUpload as a metabox do you know?

Comment: I don't think so.. but you can use the `wp.media` from within a standard meta box (non block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an action via `add_action()`, the variables that are available in the callback function are determined by the specific hook you're using. The [`load-post.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/) hook does not pass any values through to the callback function.

However, when adding meta boxes the correct hook to use is [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/), and that hook provides 2 values to the callback function `$post_type` and `$post`.

So if you want to conditionally add a meta box based on the post's page template you can use this `$post` variable with `get_page_template_slug()`:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'prefix_post_metabox_setup', 10, 2 ); // The 2 here is required to get both arguments.

function prefix_post_metabox_setup( $post_type, $post ) {
    if ( 'my-template.php' == get_page_template_slug( $post ) ) {
        add_meta_box(); // etc.
    }
}
```

Just be aware that this means that your meta boxes won't appear until after the page/post is saved with the new template. In the block editor (née Gutenberg) this might require a manual refresh.

Also, it's best practice to prefix your functions with something unique to your project. `post_metabox_setup` is too generic a name.

Comment: Thank you. The examples I've seen didn't need the post object. Thanks :)